# RTMP stream not found in AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-media-server, rtmp

Working on creating a video player, and for some reason the rtmp stream is not found. I must be missing something obvious, but can't seem to find where. The stream i am testing with is rtmp://cp67126.edgefcs.net/ondemand/mediapm/osmf/content/test/akamai_10_year_f8_512K which is definitely there.

`package
{
    import com.bfwpub.data.*;`

```
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.AsyncErrorEvent;
import flash.events.ErrorEvent;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.IOErrorEvent;
import flash.events.NetStatusEvent;
import flash.events.SecurityErrorEvent;
import flash.media.Video;
import flash.net.NetConnection;
import flash.net.NetStream;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.text.TextField;

public class BFW_VideoPlayer extends Sprite
{

    private static const PLAYER_CONFIG:String = "data/player_config.xml";

    private var _video:Video;
    private var _playerData:PlayerData;
    private var _videoData:VideoData;
    private var _controlbarData:ControlBarData;
    private var _videoPath:String;

    private var _debugTxt:TextField;

    // net connection object for net stream
    private var _ncConnection:NetConnection;
    // net stream object
    private var _nsStream:NetStream;


    public function BFW_VideoPlayer()
    {
        var xmlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
        xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadConfig);
        xmlLoader.load(new URLRequest(PLAYER_CONFIG));
    }

    private function loadConfig(e:Event):void 
    {
        var config:XML = new XML(e.target.data);

        //store data in Objects
        _playerData = new PlayerData();
        _videoData = new VideoData();
        _controlbarData = new ControlBarData();


        //populate PlayerData
        _playerData.autoPlay = config.@autoPlay;
        _playerData.autoRewind = config.@autoRewind;
        _playerData.smoothing = config.@smoothing;
        _playerData.height = config.@height;
        _playerData.isLive = config.@isLive;
        _playerData.scaleMode = config.@scaleMode;
        _playerData.width = config.@width;

        //populate VideoData
        _videoData.deliveryType = config.mediaElement.deliveryType;
        _videoData.file = config.mediaElement.file;
        _videoData.mediaPath = config.mediaElement.mediaPath;
        _videoData.streamType = config.mediaElement.streamType;
        _videoData.buffer = config.mediaElement.buffer;

        //populate ControlBarData
        _controlbarData.autoHide = config.controlBar.autoHide;
        _controlbarData.captionPath = config.controlBar.captionPath;
        _controlbarData.fullScreen = config.controlBar.fullScreen;
        _controlbarData.skinPath = config.controlBar.skinPath;

        //_videoPath = "rtmp://"+_videoData.mediaPath+_videoData.file;
        _videoPath = "rtmp://cp67126.edgefcs.net/ondemand/mediapm/osmf/content/test/akamai_10_year_f8_512K"

        createPlayer();

    }

    private function createPlayer():void
    {
        _debugTxt = new TextField();
        _debugTxt.width = 200;
        _debugTxt.height = 200;
        this.addChild(_debugTxt);

        _video = new Video();
        _video.height = _playerData.height;
        _video.width = _playerData.width;
        this.addChild(_video);
        createConnection();
    }


    private function createConnection():void
    {
        // create a new net connection, add event listener and connect
        // to null because we don’t have a media server
        _ncConnection = new NetConnection();
        _ncConnection.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netStatusHandler);
        _ncConnection.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, securityErrorHandler);
        _ncConnection.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR,errorHandler);
        _ncConnection.addEventListener(AsyncErrorEvent.ASYNC_ERROR,metaHandler);
        _ncConnection.connect(null);
    }

    /** Catch security errors. **/
    private function errorHandler(evt:ErrorEvent):void {
        trace("[ErrorEvent]"+evt.text)
    };

    /** Catch noncritical errors. **/
    private function metaHandler(evt:ErrorEvent):void {
        trace("[ErrorEvent]"+evt.text)
    };

    private function securityErrorHandler(event:SecurityErrorEvent):void {
        trace("securityErrorHandler: " + event);
    }

    public function netStatusHandler(event:NetStatusEvent):void 
    { 
        trace("["+event.info.code+"]");
        _debugTxt.text += "["+event.info.code+"]\n";
        switch (event.info.code) {
            case "NetConnection.Connect.Success":
                connectStream();
                break;
            case "NetStream.Play.StreamNotFound":
                trace("Stream not found: " + _videoPath);
                break;
        }
    }

    private function connectStream():void {
        _nsStream = new NetStream(_ncConnection);
        _nsStream.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netStatusHandler);
        _nsStream.bufferTime = _videoData.buffer;
        _nsStream.client = new Client();
        _video.attachNetStream(_nsStream);
        _video.smoothing = _playerData.smoothing;
        _nsStream.play(_videoPath);
    }   
}
```

}

Comment: Interesting, seems that if I view an FVL via http:// it works. Must be a Firewall issue maybe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yo Alex!  It's Dave, remember me from back in the day at Fusebox?  How you been man?  Cool to catch you on here.

With rtmp the connections are a little different.  Try this:

```
_ncConnection.connect("rtmp://cp67126.edgefcs.net/ondemand/mediapm/osmf/content/test");
_nsStream.play("akamai_10_year_f8_512K");
```

Comment: Thanks Dave, it's been a long time, we should catch up sometime soon.  I will test that out Tuesday. It was pretty late Friday, so i was pretty sure it would be something simple like that. Have a great holiday weekend.

Comment: Cool, happy to help.  Yea let's definitely catch up some time.